# Create a function pointer in Game Maker Studio

Tags: function-pointers, game-maker

I would like to dynamically change the script that is executed when a index in an array is called.

The following is valid syntax:

```
actions[0] = script_do_something
...
actions[n] = script_do_something_else
```

How do I execute the scripts stored in the array? If I cant, then how else could I replicate a function pointer in GMS?

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
actions[0]()
```

I would like to avoid `if` statements as I feel they will get too long and messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `script_execute` function.

```
script_execute(actions[0]);
```

also you may pass arguments:

```
script_execute(actions[0], arg1, arg2);
```